# Send data to Controller/Model and get result

Tags: php, opencart-3

I want to do second filter on opencart 3, so I got default filter files from controller and model and modified them a bit.

Now I face the problem where I want on select change to send data and receive data from server

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("select").on('change', function() {
    var url = "controller/catalog/test.php";
    var id = $("#select-option").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data: 'filter_group_id='+id,
      success: function(data) {
        $('.test').html(data)
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

and i get this

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /home/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/test.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better create a function without creating a page.

For example, if you are going to filter results from Catalog -> Products, you can create a
filter function on Product controller,
eg:

```
public function filterByGroupId(){
}
```

then you can access that function following way,

> index.php?route=catalog/product/filterByGroupId

Comment: result now is show login admin page and says invalid session/user_token

Comment: you must add user_token. `index.php?route=catalog/product/filterByGroupId&user_token={{ user_token }}` and user_token must be defined on corresponding controller file.

Comment: i did it and work but now i face another problem

atal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFilterGroup() on null 

Controller Source:
public function test(){
  if (isset($this->request->post['filter_group_id'])) {
   $filter_group_info = $this->model_catalog_damask_category->getFilterGroup($this->request->get['filter_group_id']);
  }

Comment: seems your filter in your controller file is empty... `public function filterByGroupId(){ /*here should be some your code*/
}` what code you have there?

Comment: The code I have there is:      if (isset($this->request->post['filter_group_id'])) { $filter_group_info = $this->model_catalog_damask_category->getFilterGroup($this->request->get['filter_group_id']); }

Comment: `$this->request->get['filter_group_id']` check this variable seems this are empty, or your model file is not correct.